# Would a JavaScript redirect for location based on the IP affect SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search, canonical-url, rel-canonical, shopify

So, we've got 2 separate-but-identical sites (one for US, one for the rest of the world), and were planning on redirecting visitors to their correct one, provided we can guess their location by their IP.

Obviously, a server-side redirect would be ideal, but we're using Shopify so it's a bit of a walled garden.

If I redirect a whole lot of users from one site to another in < 1 second, would Google penalise us for that? Is there a way to make it clear that they're both the same site?

Comment: IP address geo detection isn't the best.   The databases are incomplete and get the location wrong up to 10% of the time.   They don't account for people that travel but want to use the site for their home country.   Or for people doing research for a place where they are not currently located.   At most I suggest showing a message saying "You appear to be from X, our site for X has appropriate pricing and shipping options.  Would you like to switch?"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88961/discussion-on-question-by-mitcheff-would-a-javascript-redirect-for-location-base).

Comment: Honestly I think this is a question for Shopify support. We could tell you how to do this using code on your own website if you were running your own code, but Shopify probably has a special way that their system/UI handles this kind of situation so it might be best to just ask them.

Comment: Here's a guide by Shopify: https://www.shopify.com/blog/116245829-how-to-expand-your-shopify-store-to-multiple-countries

Comment: Oh wow @MaximillianLaumeister thank you so much! I can't believe that was so hard to find, haha.